# Proportion of Rhode Island's Part-Time Legislature That are Lawyers

Tags: united-states, reference-request, state-legislatures, rhode-island

I would like to know (approximately):

1. The percentage of the current [Rhode Island General Assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhode_Island_General_Assembly) that
   are lawyers.
2. Historically, the percentage that were lawyers in prior RI
   assemblies.

*Note:* I have discovered that other states have passed laws that protect individuals (e.g., time limits on closing the estate of a deceased person) whereas Rhode Island has not --- much to the chagrin of beneficiaries, while simultaneously much to the favor of lawyers who are executors.

I have heard it said that the bulk of Rhode Island's state legislature are either teachers or lawyers, because these two groups of people can make themselves available at the times that the General Assembly meets.

**Question:**
Is this an accurate statement? And, how may I ascertain the answers to the two items above?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you think teachers could make themselves available.  Teaching is one job that is almost completely inflexible: you have to work term time, there's no flexible leave.

Comment: Is there a reason to call it a part time legislature? Is there some full time one that I am not aware of? I think it would be better for the question to remove the part time reference from the title.

Comment: @James K That is the way it was put to me; but moreover, unless things have changed, some high schools in RI (I recall at least one) dismissed at 2:05pm. Teachers there, and elsewhere, might have their free-period at the last period of the day, thereby enabling them to leave a little after 1:00 pm to  go to the State House (which in RI, is not far from any point in the State.) Lastly, the Legislature convened, I recall, mid-afternoon. Hence, I surmise, were some of the reasons for the statement that was put forth to me. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Joe W Years ago, state legislators in RI were paid $5 per day (and not a salary), but the job came with (great) retirement benefits in the State pension plan, which made it more lucrative.. They met, only during certain months during the year, unless the lack of a budget required them to meet longer. And, as noted above, every point in RI is commutable to Providence within an hour or so (barring traffic)---hence, there is no need for a state representative or a state senator to live in Providence if they reside elsewhere.  Thus, a "part-time" legislature. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Meeting only part of the year isn't unique to RI but I don't think that means they should be called part time legislators as there is no such thing as a full time legislator in the state. I think it is much better to just refer to them as legislatures since that is what they do and the job is not defined by how many hours you work at it a year.

Comment: @Joe W Here is one link which makes a distinction between full and part-time legislatures: https://www.ncsl.org/research/about-state-legislatures/full-and-part-time-legislatures.aspx

Comment: @Joe W Also, RI is one state where there is no need to give up one''s full-time job even for part of the year, whereas, this, I think, would not be possible in many other states depending upon where one lived relative to the state capital.

Comment: And it is not the only state to do that. Even so I don't think it is necessary or appropriate to refer to them as such in the title

Comment: The way the title is written suggests that the legislature is split into part-time and full-time, and you're only asking about the part-time portion.

Comment: Teachers have to do quite a bit of work outside their classroom teaching periods. And legislators work outside the time that they convene formally. It's not clear that either job really allows much time for you to do the other.

Comment: ml, I tidied up your post, but your second paragraph is confusing. If you read it without the parenthetical it says "**I have discovered that other states have passed laws that protect individuals whereas Rhode Island has not** --- much to the chagrin of beneficiaries, while simultaneously much to the favor of lawyers who are executors." The bold part is especially confusing. Can you rewrite it to be clearer?

Comment: I wasn't confused by the line. It's vague regarding the kind of protections, but the parenthetical spells it out.

Comment: @johncip A sentence should be complete without the parenthetical. It's also not clear who the opposing groups to "individuals" are until you get to the end of the sentence. I don't know how lawyers benefit over beneficiaries from having different time limits (are longer limits better than shorter for individuals?), but I also don't know anything about estates.

Comment: It is worth noting that a fair number of lawyer-legislators are not lawyers who currently have an active practice of law. Some are recent law school graduates, are retired, or some are licenses but have engaged in other activities (such as other political offices, lobbying, as agents for sports and entertainment figures, etc.) in most recent years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have heard it said that the bulk of Rhode Island's state legislature are either teachers or lawyers ...

Q: *Is this an accurate statement?*

Based on the tables below, no. Attorneys and educators have made up less than half the members of prior legislatures -- near 30%, more or less.

---

Unfortunately, I could not find a list of occupations for the current members of the General Assembly. I have found that there is information in their biographies at [State of Rhode Island General Assembly](https://www.rilegislature.gov/Pages/Default.aspx) that may be used to create a table similar to those below.

Or use the **Bio** column in these lists:

- [Representatives](http://webserver.rilegislature.gov/Email/RepEmailListDistrict.asp) (75)

- [Senators](http://webserver.rilegislature.gov/Email/SenEmailListDistrict.asp) (38)

---

This is the [latest data from the National Conference of State Legislatures](https://www.ncsl.org/research/about-state-legislatures/who-we-elect-an-interactive-graphic.aspx#) for occupations. *See,* Additional Resources, Occupation, at the bottom.

[Legislators Occupations 2015](https://www.ncsl.org/Portals/1/Documents/About_State_Legislatures/Occupations.pdf) (Rhode Island)

| Occupation | Per Cent |
| --- | --- |
| Agriculture | 2% |
| Attorney | 19% |
| Business Owner | 9% |
| Business Other | 24% |
| Educator | 5% |
| Consult/Nonprofit/Professional | 6% |
| Legislator | 9% |
| Retired | 11% |
| No Data | 0% |
| Other* | 15% |

*Includes Clergy, Engineering/Science/Architecture, Communications/Arts, Public Administration, Homemaker/Student, Labor Union, Medical -- each of which does not exceed 5 percent in the national total.

---

[Legislators' Occupations for Eastern Region States- Table 2, 2007](https://www.ncsl.org/research/about-state-legislatures/legislator-occupations-eastern-region-table-2.aspx) (percentages)

| Occupation | Rhode Island |
| --- | --- |
| Attorney | 26.8% |
| Full-Time Legislator | 0.0% |
| Business Owner | 10.7% |
| Agriculture | 1.0% |
| Retired | 8.9% |
| Business: Executive/Manager | 14.3% |
| Educator: K-12 | 7.1% |
| Business: Non-manager | 7.1% |
| Consultant/Professional/Nonprofit | 8.9% |
| Real Estate | 1.8% |
| Insurance | 3.6% |
| Communications/Arts | 1.8% |
| Medical | 2.7% |
| Government Employee: Local | 0.9% |
| Educator: College | 0.0% |
| Homemaker | 0.0% |
| Engineer/Scientist/Architect | 0.9% |
| Accountant | 0.9% |
| Government Employee: State | 0.0% |
| Clergy | 0.0% |
| Labor Union | 0.9% |
| Student | 0.9% |
| Information Not Available | 0.0% |
| Insufficient Information | 0.0% |

Answer (score 2):

(Partial answer)

Going through the biographies at Ballotpedia, I can find 6 lawyers: Christopher Blazejewski, John Lombardi, Jose Batista, K. Joseph Shekarchi Robert Craven Sr. and Brian Newberry.  However not every state representative has a biography on Ballotpedia. About 25 out the 75 representatives don't have bio, so we can say that there are at least 6 lawyers, and it is reasonable to estimate that there are between 6 and 12 lawyers, out of 75 state representatives. (This is 8% to 16%)

There are a lot more teachers! (though I didn't count). There are also a lot of civil servants or professional politicians (perhaps with careers in urban planning etc), a few business managers and at least one carpenter and one firefighter.

This does not seem to be a disproportionate number of lawyers. Law is a fairly common career for someone with an interest in becoming a legislator. For example, about 40% of Federal Lawmakers are lawyers.

Comment: I couldn't find the proportion in previous assemblies.